# Where to get a .CAB file for .Net Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: updates, .net-framework, cab

I have tried searching for a .CAB file for .Net Compact Framework 3.5 and every link I've found seems to be broken. And all Microsoft will give me is an .MSI file that forces me to use an external computer and configure ActiveSync and all that on my phone.

Does anyone know of a link that works?

(yes, I know smart phone questions are generally off-topic here, but this is asking something that is just software and not really phone specific)

Answer (score 0):

MS probably doesn't offer it any other way.

Perhaps the information available in the StackOverflow link below will help your task:

[How to extract files from MSI package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549065/how-to-extract-files-from-msi-package)

Answer (score 0):

[Honeywell AIDC article on installing Compact Framework 3.5](https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-install-the-Compact-Framework-35) says:

> It is also possible to manually copy and paste the necessary .NET CF cab file to the device. However, when manually installing the .NET CF cab file to the device, it is important to copy the correct file to the device based on the OS platform running on the hardware:
>
> For Windows Mobile devices: NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab
> For Windows CE 5.0 devices: NETCFv35.wce.armv4.cab
>
> Note: The above cab files will be located under `'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE'` for 64-bit Windows PCs, or `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE'` for 32-bit Windows PCs.

So, I would recommend you install the MSI on your machine even if ActiveSync is not going to be part of your process. You can uninstall it after you've grabbed the CABs.